# Why I get null value here?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I use `$http.post` in Angular like this:

```
$scope.postComment = function(comment, post) {
    var json = JSON.stringify({
         'comments_post': post,
        'comments_text':comment});
    alert(json);

      $http.post("/api/v1/comments/", json).success(function(json, status) {
            $scope.comment = json;

      })
};
```

request payload:
[image]
my JSON for comment must look like this:

```
{
        "comments_text": "n km mn mn",
        "comments_post": {
            "id": 18,
            "title": "asdfasdf",
            "image": null,
            "height_field": 0,
            "width_field": 0,
            "content": "asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf vv",
            "check": true,
            "updated": "2016-05-25 в 18:13",
            "timestamp": "2016-05-25 в 18:13",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$24000$kSUmB51QpUSi$yWJZJt539Mj7+TLGz1tS+uIMk9dHs766opPlw8FEX0E=",
                "last_login": "2016-05-27 в 22:36",
                "is_superuser": true,
                "username": "alexandr",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "email": "alexdomoryonok@gmail.com",
                "is_staff": true,
                "is_active": true,
                "date_joined": "2016-05-25 в 10:33",
                "groups": [],
                "user_permissions": []
            }
        },
        "posted": "2016-05-27 в 22:55",
        "comments_author": {
            "id": 1,
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$24000$kSUmB51QpUSi$yWJZJt539Mj7+TLGz1tS+uIMk9dHs766opPlw8FEX0E=",
            "last_login": "2016-05-27 в 22:36",
            "is_superuser": true,
            "username": "alexandr",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "email": "alexdomoryonok@gmail.com",
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "date_joined": "2016-05-25 в 10:33",
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": []
        },
        "id": 165
    }
```

but i get django exception:
[image]

My template:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in filteredPosts" ng-if="post.check">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail post">
                            <div class="caption">
                    <span ng-if="post.image">
                    <img ng-src="{{post.image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </span>
                                <p>{{post.content| limitTo:200}}...</p>
                                <p>Aвтор: <a ng-href='/authsys/{{post.user.username}}/'>{{post.user.username}}</a></p>
                                <p>Создано: {{post.timestamp}}</p>
                                <p>Обновлено: {{post.updated}}</p>

                                <div class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="user.user == post.user.username" method="delete"
                                     ng-click="deletePost(post)">Удалить
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-if="comment.comments_post.id == post.id">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <span ng-if="user.user == comment.comments_author.username">
                                          <a href="" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" style="margin-left: 95%"><i
                                                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                         </span>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        {{comment.comments_text}}
                                    </div>
                                    <p style="margin-left: 85%"><a
                                            href="/authsys/{{comment.comments_author.username}}/">{{comment.comments_author.username}}</a>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" ng-model="text">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Добавить" ng-click="postComment(text, post)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

models.py:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
        ordering = ['-timestamp', '-updated']

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              height_field='height_field',
                              width_field='width_field',
                              verbose_name='Изображение')
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, verbose_name='высота')
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, verbose_name='ширина')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    check = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Одобрить')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)  # User
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # for detail view
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/posts/detail/{0}".format(self.id)

class Comments(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'comments'
        verbose_name = 'Комментарии'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'

    comments_text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Ваш комментарий')
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comments_author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    comments_post = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
```

Comment: Where you are querying the database to get this content.

Comment: i use angular for mapping on page($http.get)

Comment: @MatheusSilva  i add models.py if it can help you to resolve problem

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. you are putting a null in `comments_post_id` which means you are not assigning a value to the `commens_post` field in your `Comments` model. Remove all the irrelevent code and post only the bits that save the record.

Comment: @e4c5 did you read my question?

Comment: @e4c5 check my request payload

Answer (score 3):

Basically what the error looks like to be, your database has a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `comments_post_id` and you are trying to insert something with a value of null to that column.

Well, your problem is here:

```
$scope.postComment = function(comment, post) {
var json = JSON.stringify({
     'comments_post': post,
    'comments_text':comment});
alert(json);

  $http.post("/api/v1/comments/", json).success(function(json, status) {
        $scope.comment = json;

  })
};
```

You are inserting in your database (at least posting to that route to insert) only a few params, your table needs a `comments_post_id` value, it cannot be null. I dont know how's your relation between tables, but your `comments_post_id` myst have a value. Or you pass via post a value for it, or do something else.

// UPDATE

After looking at you code, you have a relation between comments and posts. I dont know how it works with python but, with other modern mvc frameworks you have to have one thing inserted to have this primary key on the foreign key of the relation.

For example.

You have to insert a post and than insert a comment referencing the post. What i would do with angular (pseudo algorithm).

```
var post_id = 123;  // got from someplace
var json = JSON.stringify({
         'comments_post': post,
        'comments_text':comment,
        'comments_post_id' : post_id});

$http.post("/api/v1/comments/", json).success(function(json, status) {
            $scope.comment = json;

      })
```

Comment: look at models.py. "comments_post_id" its just relation in database

Comment: I dunno that much more of python to help you, but, something i know from modern mvc frameworks is that: you have to have inserted the model from the relation on the database to "connect" it to the other model, so it will have the foreign key on the related model. In you example, you have to have inserted a post and than insert the comment referencing that post id. Was i clear enough?

Comment: post exist, i need  add comment to it

Comment: you right, just discover how to do it. I "proposed" a way to do it.

Comment: "comments_post_id" its just relation in database, its not a field in model

Comment: ""comments_post_id" its just relation in database, its not a field in model" are relations in the database conjured out of thin air? no they correspond to things that you enter in your model.

Comment: @e4c5 its what i'm proposing. Wheter its a relation, you still need to fill it out, it wont fill itself by magic.

Comment: exactly my point so instead of expecting magic, write the code for it.

Comment: @MatheusSilva 
it did not help , you just wrote the obvious thing. The problem is solved not